# How to add an image to a JQuery Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am having problems trying to add a Picture to my dialog box, Basically my Dialog Box is called when a user clicks a cell within the table.

```
    <td class="dialog">English</td>
```

which is then linked to the Div

```
<div id="dialog" title="LessonSelected">

</div>
```

Next here is my JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
        $('#dialog').html($(this).html()); 
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {
                "Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(true);
                },
                "Cancel Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

However when I try to add img markup within the div the image appears on the interface and not in the dialog box also when the cell is clicked the text within the cell appears in the dialog box automatically which is not what is needed I do want to get the value though it just appears automatically and being new to JQuery I do not know how to format this or add further text before or after it. Is anyone able to diagnose my problem ?

Comment: If I understand you right, when I click on "English" a dialog pops up and the word English appears in the dialog?  Where does it show up?  And this is only when you've added an image to the dialog?

Comment: Forgot to ask, are you adding the image dynamically based upon the clicked cell?

Comment: would be nice if you could add a fiddle where we can see the issue

Comment: well first of all the line `$('#dialog').html($(this).html());` copies the cell content into the dialog div... where `$(this)` is the cell you clicked that called the function

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your jquery http://jsfiddle.net/q4m68/ the only this is that it's adding the text from class dialog in the id dialog div,not an image..

Comment: Yeah, as msbodetti says, other than the fact that your example has nothing to do with an image, the code seems to work just fine.  I changed it a little by chaining the .html() to the end of the dialog instantiation though.  $("#dialog").dialog(...).html($(this).html());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6UGn/1/)** : using jQuery **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){ 

        $('#dialog').append('<img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/><br/>').append($(this).html());

       //append image through JS

        $('#dialog').dialog({
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {
                "Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(true);
                },
                "Cancel Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

OR

```
<div id="dialog" title="LessonSelected">
    <span><img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet! Sorry I missed the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dialog `autoOpen = false` and then open it when you click

HTML

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialogBox" title="LessonSelected">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/opening/cta.png" />
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable:false,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Enrol": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(true);
            },
            "Cancel Enrol": function()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(false);
            }
        }
    });

  $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
    $('#dialog').dialog("open");
  });
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/F9uR3/

Comment: Defiantly the Answer I needed, I just wondered how would I be able to readd the text to the Selection of a Cell after the image ?